# Barcode on SSRS query based report in dynamics 365?

Tags: reporting-services, barcode, dynamics-365

I need to add an id converted to barcode on a query based report in dynamics 365. How can I do that?
I tried to change the font to BC C128 Narrow, 40pt, but the font cannot be scanned.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code 128 requires a checksum to be calculated and inserted into the string. It is difficult because the resulting checksum character is not always valid ASCII.

If your ID number is all numeric, you are in luck and should use a Code 39 barcode font for simplicity's sake instead. Otherwise, you will need a program to calculate the proper checksum, convert it into the proper character code and insert it into the string before applying the font.